# Exporting an E4 Application

Tags: java, eclipse, export, exe, e4

I have a feature based E4 application that I'd like to export as an executable project (.exe since I'm under windows).

I'm following the automated procedure called "Export Project Wizard" but despite I'm getting a .exe file + some JAR's in the same export folder, when I run it I get this error message: "org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/test/test1"

com.test.test1 is an external plugin which I included in the depedency tab, and it seems that Eclipse won't find it.

How can I work it out? Should it not automatically export all the required plugins?

I also tried to export that plugin manually, as JAR, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Export > Plug-in Development > Eclipse product'. This will require you to specify the xxx.product file that was created when you created your e4 application.

You can also launch the same wizard from the xxx.product editor by clicking 'Use the Eclipse product export wizard'.

You must configure your xxx.product file to specify all the features that you are using - your own features and the standard Eclipse features (on the Dependencies tab). For example on my product I have:

```
my feature
org.eclipse.e4.rcp
org.eclipse.emf.common
org.eclipse.emf.ecore
```

the 3 Eclipse features are the minimum needed for an e4 application.

Your feature must list all your plugins in its `feature.xml` plus any dependencies that are not covered in any other feature. Every plugin you want to use must appear in one of the features.

Comment: Greg it's what I did, I used the "Eclipse product export wizard" from the .product config. Anyway my application is made of 2 plugins declared in a feature. So probably I have to work it out on the feature project. It's something like this equation: feature = plugin1 + plugin2 = myapp. The project.product is only available in the the plugin1, but i have got in trouble with plugin2 (that's called com/test/test1 in the previous example).

Comment: Just list all your plugins in the feature.xml. Also any external plugins that are not in the other features

Comment: Yes they're listed and if I run it in eclipse, my app works like a charm. The problem occurs when I try to export it as an executable application outside eclipse. I have to deliver my app so I need a .exe or any other runnable format which would work under windows.

Comment: Well it should run, I do this all the time. Look at the directory structure that is built and see if all the plugins you expect are present.

Comment: Yes in the runtime environment, eclipse is generating a folder called "plugins". It's weird that the missing plugin: test1 is included as folder and not as .jar . What do you think?

Comment: Plugins can be packaged as folders or jars (look in the Eclipse installation to see both). Does the folder contain class files in the correct places? Does it have a proper MANIFEST.MF? Basically it sounds like a problem with the plugin rather than the build

Comment: Hi greg I solved it. It was a problem bound to the binary build of MANIFEST. I didn't include some files and so it didn't run properly. Now since I have an XML file to be read as soon as the app starts and it's not automatically exported, do you have any idea how to fix this?